# JS for mouseover image upload button (like Facebook)

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, upload, hover

I'm trying to build an image upload system like Facebook's where when you mouseover an image, a button (a div, not an actual html button) appears to select an image.  So far, I'm using jQuery's hover method.  The problem is, when I hover over the image, the button appears, but then when I hover over the button, the function assumes I'm no longer hovering over the image, and the button disappears.  Of course then since the button is gone, I'm hovering over the image again and the button reappears.  The end result is this sort of flickering effect when I move my mouse on the image.

I can't seem to figure out a way around it.  I tried creating a separate hover event for the button itself that removes the hover event for the image and then replaces it on mouseout, but the image mouseout event seems to fire first, and it does nothing.

Only thing I can think is to use a setTimeout, but this seems sloppy.  Seeing as Facebook is doing something similar, I'm sure there's a super clean way to handle it.

Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using [mouseenter()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) instead of hover() to handle bubbling

> The mouseenter event differs from mouseover in the way it handles
>   event bubbling. If mouseover were used in this example, then when the
>   mouse pointer moved over the Inner element, the handler would be
>   triggered. This is usually undesirable behavior. The mouseenter event,
>   on the other hand, only triggers its handler when the mouse enters the
>   element it is bound to, not a descendant. So in this example, the
>   handler is triggered when the mouse enters the Outer element, but not
>   the Inner element.

Comment: Using mouseleave() (the opposite of mouseenter() ) didn't explicitly solve my problem, but it helped me figure it out.  I was attaching the  event to the image tag itself, and since the button was not contained as a child of the image tag, it wouldn't work.  I ended up wrapping both the image tag and the button in a parent div and then attaching a mouseover event to THAT.  Can't believe I didn't think about that before.

Problem solved!