# Problems with hide() delay on top/sub level menu BUT cancel hide() when mouse enters again

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I am having problems with onmouseout/over delay in my menus. I found by changing the setTimeout numbers from 100 to say 2000 it delays the top level menu from hide but not sub level menu and on new onmouseover they still hide, here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

On onmouseout of either primary menu or primary and secondary menu, delay hide for 2-3 seconds BUT ALSO if user returns with onmouseover either element it will cancel the delay and keep showing them.

Most help I find online is just for hide delay but not cancelling it on new onmouseover.

Here is my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/MQ2cg/4/

```
jQuery.fn.hoverWithDelay = function (inCallback, outCallback, delay) {
    this.each(function (i, el) {
        var timer;
        $(this).hover(function () {
            timer = setTimeout(function () {
                timer = null;
                inCallback.call(el);
            }, delay);
        }, function () {
            if (timer) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                timer = null;
            } else outCallback.call(el);
        });
    });
};
$(document).ready(function () {
    var hovering = {
        mainMenu: false,
        categories: false
    };

    function closeSubMenus() {
        $('ul.sub-level').css('display', 'none');
    }
    closeSubMenus();

    function closeMenuIfOut() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (!hovering.mainMenu && !hovering.categories) {
                $('#navigation').fadeOut('fast', closeSubMenus);
            }
        }, 100);
    }
    $('ul.top-level li').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('ul').show();
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('ul').hide();
        closeMenuIfOut();
    }, 100);
    $('#categories').hoverWithDelay(function () {
        $('#navigation').show();
        hovering.categories = true;
    },

    function () {
        hovering.categories = false;
        closeMenuIfOut();
    }, 175);
    $('#navigation').hover(function () {
        hovering.mainMenu = true;
    }, function () {
        hovering.mainMenu = false;
    });
    $('#categories').click(function () {
        window.location.href = $('a', this).attr('href');
    });
});
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

this questions seem to be similar:

[JS for mouseover image upload button (like Facebook)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588112/js-for-mouseover-image-upload-button-like-facebook)

as Amin Eshaq pointed out use mouseenter / mouseleave

here is working code:

```
    $(this).bind({
            'mouseenter' : function () {
                    timer = setTimeout(function () {
                            timer = null;
                            inCallback.call(el);
                    }, delay);
            },
            'mouseleave' : function () {
                    if (timer) {
                            clearTimeout(timer);
                            timer = null;
                    } else outCallback.call(el);
            }            
    });
```

Comment: I tried changing hover to mouseenter but then everything stopped working.

Comment: have you used $('selector').bind('mouseenter', function() {}); ? cause there is no shorthand for mouseenter...

Comment: Where exactly would I insert your code into mine? Please forgive the ignorance on this, just haven't been able to figure it out.